# How to attach file to Flask Mail received from Flask Form?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-mail

I am developing a website in Python Flask. What I have to do is to get uploaded file in one of the forms and attach it to mail. I tried solution given in similar question but it gives following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'

What am I doing wrong? I am beginner in python and flask.
Here's my code:

```
class UploadForm(Form):
    branch = StringField('branch', validators = [DataRequired()])
    year = StringField('year', validators = [DataRequired()])
    sub = StringField('sub', validators = [DataRequired()])
    paper = FileField('Logo', validators = [Required()])

def uploadPaper(form):
    msg = Message('New upload request', sender = ADMINS[0], recipients = ADMINS)
    msg.body = 'text body'
    msg.html = 'Branch: ' + form.branch.data + '<br />' + 'Year: ' + form.year.data + '<br />' + 'Subject: ' + form.sub.data
    msg.attach(form.paper.data.filename, 'application/octect-stream', form.paper.data.read())
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)
    return "success"
```

I am calling uploadPaper() function on validating the form.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error you've got means you're trying to read a file from a string.

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'`

This happens because your uploadPaper() function is returning a string (Or 'str') instead of a 'file' object. Since Python is object-oriented, your script is probably trying to read the "filename" attribute from the file object.

I can also see in your function that there is an object with the attribute you're trying to use, here at

```py
msg.attach(form.paper.data.filename, 'application/octect-stream', form.paper.data.read())
```

It looks like the `form.paper.data` object has the property "filename" you're trying to user later on.

Why don't you try `return form.paper.data` instead of `return "success"`?

Comment: Actually, I tried printing type of form.paper.data and it shows 'str' which is name of the file I am uploading. I don't know how to use form.paper.data to attach my file to an email.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to say. `form.paper.data` should not be a string, it's supposed to be an object. You're trying to do `msg.attach(object.filename, 'application/octet-stream', object.read())` when your object is just a string. Strings (or 'str') don't have attributes. Please show your imported modules at the top of the code so that I can see what you're using.

Comment: here are my imports:  `from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, request`
`from app import app, mail`
`from .forms import SearchForm, RequestForm, UploadForm`
`from app import searchBar`
`import os, os.path, time, subprocess, datetime`
`from flask_mail import Message`
`from config import ADMINS`
`from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename `

Comment: I made it word using `request`. But I want to know why my previous approach wasn't working.